# Get the Device information in Windows 8 app using Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8

Is it possible to get the device information on which the App is installed. I need to get the info such as:

1. Device OS: (Windows 8)
2. OS Version
3. Device ID (Some unique id of the machine on which the app is installed)

Comment: What is your app's environment: native web browser, Phonegap or what? Also what do you mean by "installed"?